# The Wieferich prime $1093$ divides $3^{1036}-1$.

Tags: number-theory

I found that the Wieferich prime $1093$ divides $3^{1036}-1$.
Does $1093$ divides infinitely many $3^{k}-1$, with k a positive integer? And what features must $3^{k}-1$ have to be divisible by $1093$?

Comment: Well, if it divides $3^{1036}-1$ is will divide $3^{1036m}-1=(3^{1036}-1)(3^{1036(m-1) } + 3^{1036(m-2)} + .... + 3^{1036} + 1)$ for all natural $m$ so... yes.

Answer (score 2):

We see that $1093|3^7-1$. Now,

$$1093|3^k-1\Leftrightarrow 1093|(3^k-1)-(3^7-1) \Leftrightarrow 1093|3^k-3^7 \Leftrightarrow 1093|3^{k-7}-1.$$

We can see, by repeatedly subtracting $7$, that $1093|3^{7m}-1$ for any $m$. Now, if $1093|3^k-1$ for some other $k$, then

$$1093|3^{k-7m}-1$$

for any $m$, and we can pick such an $m$ so $1\leq k-7m\leq 6$. However,

$$0<3^1-1<3^6-1=728<1093,$$

so $1093\nmid 3^k-1$ for any $7\nmid k$.

Comment: I'm curious how you determined $1093|3^7 -1$.

Comment: Oh, never mind!

Answer (score 1):

Notice $a^m -1 = (a-1)(a^{m-1} + a^{m-2}+... + a + 1)$

So if $1093|a^{1036}-1$ then $1093|a^{1036m} - 1$ so there are infinite $k = 1036m$ where this is true.

Also remember Fermat's little Theorem.  If $1093$ is prime than $3^{1092}\equiv 1 \pmod{1093}$ (and so $1093|3^{1092}-1$).  As a consequence.  If $3^a \equiv 1\pmod {1093}$ and $a$ is the smallest such number (other than zero) then $m|1092$.

Also if $3^{m}\equiv 1 \pmod {1093}$ and $3^k \equiv 1 \pmod {1093}$ then $3^{\gcd(m,n)}\equiv 1 \pmod {1093}$. (and if $a$ is the smallest power so that $3^a \equiv 1 \pmod{1093}$ then $a|\gcd(m,n)$.

$1092 = 2^2*3*7*3*13$.  And $1036 = 2^2*7*37$ and $\gcd(1092,1036)=28$.  So $3^{28} \equiv 1 \pmod {1093}$.

Its possible that some factors of $28$ are such powers and simple testing finds $3^7 =   2187 = 2*1093 + 1$ so $1093|3^7 -1$.

So $1093|3^{7m}-1$.

If $3^k\equiv 1 \pmod {1093}$ then $3^{\gcd(7,k)}\equiv 1 \pmod {1093}$ but if $k $ is not a multiple of $7$ then $\gcd(7,k) = 1$ but $3^1 \not \equiv 1 \pmod{1093}$.

So $k = 7m$ are all and the only solutions to $1093|3^k -1$.

Comment: I've corrected two *Pentium-bugs* on the number *1093* ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $$r_k\triangleq 3^k-1\mod 1093$$then $$r_{k+1}{=3^{k+1}-1\mod 1093\\=3^{k+1}-3+2\mod 1093\\=\Big(3\cdot(3^{k}-1)\mod 1093\Big)+2\mod 1093\\=3r_k+2\mod 1093}$$Based on this and with $r_1=2\mod1093=2 $ we obtain$$r_1=2\\r_2=8\\r_3=26\\r_4=80\\r_5=242\\r_6=728\\r_7=0\\r_8=2\\.\\.\\.$$by a simple induction we conclude that:$$r_k=0\iff k=7u\quad\text{for some }u\in\Bbb Z$$therefore$$3^n\equiv 1\mod 1093\iff n=7u$$and all the answers are as follows:$$3^{7n}\equiv 1\mod 1093\quad,\quad n\in \Bbb N$$